# JSF: Navigation issue (Ajax / Non-Ajax)

Tags: ajax, jsf, navigation, primefaces

When the following (PrimeFaces) button is pressed

```
<p:commandButton value="Search"
                 actionListener="#{personController.searchPersons}"
                 update="resultTable"/>
```

I load a list of objects and display them in a table on the current page. This is done via an Ajax call.

Now I'd like to do the following: If only one object is found, don't update the result table but link directly to the "detail page". (e.g. `detail.xhtml`)

How can this be done?

I know that i can control the navigation via the return value of my `searchPersons()` method. But It doesn't work as it should. I think it has to do with the `update="resultTable"` of my button. But I currently don't know how to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring in some JS in `oncomplete` attribute. It will be executed when the bean action and the partial update is completed. You can change the window location in JS by assigning `window.location` a new URL.

Here's a random kickoff example, assuming that you've a persons table with id `persons` and that the detail link look something like `<a class="detail" href="detail.xhtml?id=123">` somewhere in the table row.

```
oncomplete="var $persons = jQuery('#persons tbody tr'); if ($persons.length == 1) window.location = $persons.find('a.detail').attr('href');"
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I did it now a little different but you brought me on the right track! `if (resultTable.getPaginator().getTotalRecords() == 1) $('#resultTable button:first').trigger('click');` resultTable is a PrimeFaces DataTable and the button sets the selected element and links to the detail page.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it was just a kickoff example. You see, I know nothing about your exact view structure :)